# How does sendBroadcast(intent) work internally

Tags: android, android-intent

Curious to know how sendBroadcast works internally, and if someone could please explain that would be nice. Please point me to the actual implementation.

I was looking at android source

ContextWrapper.java contains the implementation for the abstract method of sendBroadcast(), which basically just calls the base implementation. But where is the actual implementation where sendBroadcast notifies all the registered BroadcastReceivers?

```
@Override
public void sendBroadcast(Intent intent) {
    mBase.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Edit: mBase is from Context class, which is an abstract class, and sendBroadcast was an abstract method definition there, without any implementation.

```
public abstract void sendBroadcast(Intent intent)
```

Comment: Eh, whatever mBase class is find and check that file. And so on.

Comment: @Alex - i did., mBase is from Context, which is an abstract class, and sendBroadcast was an abstract method definition there, no implementation. public abstract void sendBroadcast(Intent intent);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#L893) is the sendBroadcast implementation.

Comment: ahh!., thanks so much.. no wonder i missed it., i couldn't see this file under eclipse. I have the android sources pointed to the sources folder,. and under android app., no ContextImpl.java.. Hmm.. wonder why.. i think i should pull the entire source tree using repo and run cscope on it!.. Thanks so much